# Cakephp3 able to save data but cannot save associations

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi so I'm trying to save data through Cakephp3 framework. I have two tables Measures and MeasuresUsers. Measures has many MeasuresUsers

```
$data = [
 'name' => $this->request->data['name'],
 'description' => $this->request->data['description'],
 'deleted' => $this->request->data['deleted'],
 'chart_type' => $this->request->data['chart_type'],
 'public' => $this->request->data['public'],
 'user_id' => $this->request->data['user_id']
];
$measure = $this->Measures->newEntity($data,['associated' => ['MeasuresUsers']]);

$measure['measures_users'] = [
                    'user_id' => $user['id'],
                    'chart_type' => $this->request->data['chart_type'],
                    'deleted' => $this->request->data['deleted'],
                    'public' => $this->request->data['public']
];
$this->Measures->save($measure)
```

I'm able to save data into Measures table but not into the associative table (MeasuresUsers). I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help or comments is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@HarryM. is close, but you want to put your data into the `$data` array before creating the entity (the `associated` tag is kinda pointless if you're not providing that data!), and since it's a hasMany relation, I think you need to have the data in an array of arrays:

```
$data = [
    'name' => $this->request->data['name'],
    'description' => $this->request->data['description'],
    'deleted' => $this->request->data['deleted'],
    'chart_type' => $this->request->data['chart_type'],
    'public' => $this->request->data['public'],
    'user_id' => $this->request->data['user_id'],
    'measures_users' => [
        [
            'user_id' => $user['id'], // Should this be $this->request->data['user_id'] instead?
            'chart_type' => $this->request->data['chart_type'],
            'deleted' => $this->request->data['deleted'],
            'public' => $this->request->data['public'],
        ],
    ],
];
$measure = $this->Measures->newEntity($data, ['associated' => ['MeasuresUsers']]);

$this->Measures->save($measure);
```

Comment: Actually `measures_users` is the correct default property name according to the conventions. **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations**

Comment: Ah thanks!, if you could edit your solution to match cakephp conventions that'll be great!

Answer (score -1):

Coming from CakePHP 2.x, I see your associate model is **MeasuresUsers**.

When you're setting the associated data in

```
$measure['measures_users'] = [
    'user_id' => $user['id'],
    'chart_type' => $this->request->data['chart_type'],
    'deleted' => $this->request->data['deleted'],
    'public' => $this->request->data['public']
];
```

Trying changing $measure['measures_users'] to $measure['MeasuresUsers']:

```
$measure['MeasuresUsers'] = [
    'user_id' => $user['id'],
    'chart_type' => $this->request->data['chart_type'],
    'deleted' => $this->request->data['deleted'],
    'public' => $this->request->data['public']
];
```

CakePHP's model conventions usually assume camel casing of what you have in the database e.g. DB Table it movie_tickets and Cake would expect is as MovieTicket unless otherwise declared in the Model itself.